# Problem with routesand actions on Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been learning rails for a few days and I'm currently doing a friend list project with user authentication, etc. The problem is that i cannot call to a delete action with out using the instruction 'button_to'. Here's an example:

```
        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'Sign In', new_user_session_path, class:"nav-link" %>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= button_to 'Sign Out', destroy_user_session_path,method: :delete ,class:"nav-link" %>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'Edit Profile', edit_user_registration_path, class:"nav-link" %>
        </li>
```

These are my navbar links and you can see that i had to put 'button_to' instead of 'link_to', but i didn't want that because it's a different component. Do you know why is this problem?

Here i put the version of all technologies that i work with:

- Rails: **Rails 6.1.4**
- Ruby: **ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]**
- Gem: **3.1.2**
- SQlite3: **3.31.1 2020-01-27 19:55:54 3bfa9cc97da10598521b342961df8f5f68c7388fa117345eeb516eaa837balt1
  **
- Nvm: **0.37.2**
- Node: **v14.17.4**

-OS: **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS**

**application.js**

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in 
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference 
// that code so it'll be compiled. 

//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs 
import Rails from "@rails/ujs" 
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks" 
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage" 
import "channels" 
Rails.start() 
Turbolinks.start() 
ActiveStorage.start()
```

Please help and thank you very much!

Comment: What happens when you use link_to, do you receive a specific error or the link just doesn't do anything?

Comment: Yes, i recieve the next message from my terminal: ```Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2021-08-11 16:56:22 +0200
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"):```

Comment: I forgot to mention that the method that i use for the delete action is the specified in the routes table for DELETE :  destroy_user_session_path  DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)  

devise/sessions#destroy

Comment: According to [every SO Post](https://www.google.com/search?q=link_to+method+delete+site%3A+stackoverflow.com) I just ran through this can be caused by failure to include [rails-ujs](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/main/actionview/app/assets/javascripts) or [jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) please make sure you have one of these libraries in your application.js file

Comment: // This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//= require jquery 
//= require jquery_ujs
import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()

Comment: I edited my friends/app/javascript/packs/application.js with the content and installed  rails-ujs (yarn add @rails/ujs) and jquery_ujs(yarn add jquery-ujs)

Comment: It works before adding in friends/config/initializers/devise.rb "  config.sign_out_via = [:get,:delete] " in the last line. But it still fails in a table with the same logic.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using devise:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to destroy_user_session_path(:authenticity_token => form_authenticity_token()), method: :delete, class: 'tooltips' do %>
    <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Log Out
  <% end %>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this helps and how adding a parameter will changes GET request to a DELETE request?

Comment: I triedto test with this code example and uninstalling each rails/ujs and jquery-ujs both and using one of them  but it's still printthe same error: No route matches [GET] "/users/sign_out"

Comment: inside config/initializers/device.rb check line:   config.sign_out_via = [:get,:delete]

Comment: @vidurpunj it worjked. I put that order at the final line below the 'end' and restarted. Thank you very much guys!!! but it continues failing in a table with the same order

Comment: The order is the following one: <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', friend, method: :delete, form:{data:{confirm: 'Are you sure?'}},class:"btn btn-danger"%></td>